# How to create a ComboBox autofill using SQLite Data Reader

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have two Combo-Boxes like this

[image]

I need to create an auto-fill feature for the 1st Combo-Box. It should list the EmployeeID if Search-By Field is specified as Employee-Number. Similarly it should list Employee First Name along with Last Name if the Search-By Field is Employee-Name.

How can I do this? I have no clue, I am doing this for the first time. I am using SQLite, Visual Studio 2010.

```
  Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT " & Search & " FROM EmployeeTable WHERE Status LIKE '" & Status & "'"
        Dim myConnString As String = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database\SimpleDB.db3"
        Dim sqConnection As New SQLiteConnection(myConnString)
        Dim sqCommand As New SQLiteCommand(mySelectQuery, sqConnection)
        sqConnection.Open()

        Try
            ' Always call Read before accessing data.
            Dim sqReader As SQLiteDataReader = sqCommand.ExecuteReader()
            Dim j As Integer = sqReader.FieldCount
            While sqReader.Read()

'''''''''''''''''''''''Here, Don't know how to list the items from the query reult into the combo-box
                End While

            'Close Reader after use
            sqReader.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Show Message on Error
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            'At Last Close the Connection
            sqConnection.Close()
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure entirely what you are asking but I think this is it.
In the `SelectedIndex` changed event you would have something similar to the code below. You can add an `If` statement to check what you are querying for and adjust your query accordingly.

```
Dim dt as New DataTable

Try
            Using sqlConn

            sqlConn.Open()

                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("your query")

                    cmd.Connection = sqlConn
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text


                   Dim reader as SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                   dt.Load(reader)
                End Using


        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try

With yourComboBox
     .DataSource = dt
     .DataValueField = "columName you want to be the value of the item"
     .DataTextField = "columnName of the text you want displayed"
End With
```

Comment: Hoe can I do it using Data reader instead of a adapter. I heard data-reader is faster

Comment: @Failed_Noob check my post again.

Comment: It gives an error and says DataValueField and DataTextField are not a member of ComboBox

Comment: @Failed_Noob, sorry I thought this was an asp.net question too. Use: `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following properties for the combo-box: AutoCompleteMode, AutoCompleteSource, AutoCompleteCustomSource.

Select the appropriate AutoCompleteMode. See details on the different modes at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx).
For AutoCompleteSource, choose either ListItems (in which case the source will be the items of the ComboBox) or CustomSource. Should you choose CustomSource, set the appropriate source as the value of the ComboBox's AutoCompleteCustomSource property.

This should provide you with enough details to do what you're looking for.
The other requirements you've listed - such as taking the data from an SQLite database or changing between employee name and employee number - won't affect the way you work with the AutoComplete feature.

Comment: Please tell me how to enter the query result into combo-box list item. Look at the above code